# Cannot build Opencv project with cmake

Tags: c++, windows, opencv, makefile, cmake

So , I'm trying to build an opencv project using cmake , but using both the GUI utility and the command line tool , but keep having the same error popping up

```
  CMake Warning at cmake/modules/FindOpenCV.cmake:160 (message):
  Found OpenCV 2.4.3 Windows Super Pack but it has not binaries compatible
  with your configuration.
      You should manually point CMake variable OpenCV_DIR to your build of OpenCV library.
  Call Stack (most recent call first):
  CMakeLists.txt:48 (FIND_PACKAGE)
```

If anyone here please could help me here , that would be great;

Comment: What happens if you follow the warning's advice?

Comment: I still get the same results

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Change OpenCV_DIR entry under OpenCV in CMake from C:\OpenCV\cmake to C:\OpenCV\build. It will solve your problem.

Answer (score 0):

I think your CMake variable `OpenCV_DIR` is not pointing to the correct location. Have a look at where your opencv binaries are kept and where the `OpenCV_DIR` variable is pointing to

---

If you are using window give the command `setx` and find out the correct value of it

Comment: Thanks , but I did that and still get the same results